# How do I get the HTML between two div elements in Python

Tags: python, html

I'm trying to scrape all the paragraphs from Wikipedia that come between the main heading of the page and the table of contents. I noticed that they always come between two div elements as shown below:

```
<div id="some-div">...</div>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
<div id="some-other-div">...</div>
```

I want to grab all of the HTML between the two div elements (not just the text)
Looking for a solution in Python.

Comment: Look at `BeautifulSoup` library for working with HTML

Comment: Try using the [`html.parser`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/html.parser.html?highlight=html.parse#module-html.parser) library.

Comment: Why the [tag:javascript] and [tag:css] tags?

Comment: @Robᵩ sorry about that, my mistake :)

Comment: Should we take you to mean that you want everything from `<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading" lang="en">Python (programming language)</h1>` to `<h2>Contents</h2>`? Rather than concerning ourselves with `<div>` elements?

Comment: @BillBell, yes  but apart from this part `From Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia
This article is about the programming language. For the snake genus, see Python (genus). For other uses, see Python (disambiguation).`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt you can depend on utterly consistent formatting. However, this seems to work for the 'Python (programming language)' page, where the introductory text is delimited by the 'Contents' box.

I offer a few notes:

- **fetchPreviousSiblings** returns the paragraphs in reverse order.
- I would check the length of **contents** against the unlikely possibility of more than one occurrence.
- It's almost certainly necessary with this approach to check for rubbish.

```
    from urllib.request import urlopen
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    URL = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)'
    HTML = str ( urlopen ( URL ) . read() )
    soup = BeautifulSoup ( HTML )
    contents = soup.findAll('div', attrs={'id': 'toc'})
    paras = contents[0].fetchPreviousSiblings('p')
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I noticed that the table of contents was always an HTML table. So I added a break condition and grabbed all the paragraphs before that using `for link in soup,findAll('p')` The for loop added the paragraphs to an array as I needed them to be. And had a break condition if a table was encountered. Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0):

With BeautifulSoup you will find the first div and the second div by their ids:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
bs = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")

first_div = bs.find(id="some-div")
second_div = bs.find(id="some-other-div")
```

After this, we create a list with all the elements in between the two divs (converted to strings) and afterwards join them together. For this we loop through all the siblings after the first_div and break when we reach the second div:

```
in_between = []
for sibling in first_div.next_siblings:
    if sibling == second_div:
        break
    else:
        in_between.append(str(sibling))

in_between = "".join(in_between)
```

The previous codeblock can be replaced by this list comprehension in one line:

```
in_between = "".join([str(sibling) for sibling in takewhile(lambda x: x != second_div, first_div.next_siblings)])
```